# Is creating a new list object via multiplication by one with an existing list equivalent to making a deep copy?

Tags: python, list, deep-copy

For example, say I want to make a deep copy of a list `a`, called `b`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Is there any difference between:

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

and:

```
b = a*1
```

In both cases I've created a new object (i.e `id(a) == id(b)` is `False`), so are there any practical differences I should understand?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. One is a deep copy the other is a shallow copy. In this *particular* case there is no difference, but if you had mutable objects this could lead to unexpected results

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So the difference would become apparent when making a copy of a container of mutable objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they aren't equivalent.  The multiplication operator makes only a shallow copy. A deep copy means that the references within the list are also copied (that is, new references are created), while a shallow copy only makes a new copy of the top-level reference but not the references within, as demonstrated below:

```
import copy
a = [[],[]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
c = a * 1
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    print(id(v), id(b[i]), id(c[i]))
```

This outputs:

```
31231832 31261480 31231832
31260800 31261400 31260800
```

Comment: In that case, is using the multiplication operator identical to making a shallow copy?  Is there any reason I would want to use b = copy.copy(a) instead?  Thanks!

Comment: Using `b = copy.copy(a)` makes it more readable but also slightly more verbose. A more common and Pythonic way to making a shallow copy is to use `b = a[:]`.

Comment: @trillian no, aside from clarity. With lists, you usually just use `my_list.copy()`. A more standard idiom is simply `my_list[:]` which pythonistas will understand. I find `my_list*1` more obscure.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga, yes I agree that `my_list*1` is more obscure, in fact my question came about in trying to understand someone else's code that is full of the `my_list*1` syntax!

Comment: The code I'm looking over has many instances of the following: `a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])` and `b=a[:]*1`.  In this context, where the multiplication is happening with the contents of the container, we have to equivalent of a deep copy, no?